# MSVC can find matching constructor but gcc and clang couldn't

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

So recently I've been interested in making a tagged tuple, which is a tuple but you can use the get function with tags instead of indices. The code is kinda long so bare with me.

```
// tagged_tuple.hpp
// simple class to hold two types
// works with incomplete types, important for our use case
template <class First, class Second> struct type_pair {
    using first = First;
    using second = Second;
};

namespace detail {
    // gets info about a classes name tag (key -> value type mapping) from the class
    template <class T>
    struct name_tag_traits {
        // aliases for our specific use case
        using tag_type = typename T::first;
        using value_type = typename T::second;
    };

    // helper alias, turns a list of TypePairs supplied to tagged_tuple to a list of
    // key/tag/name types
    template <class T>
    using name_tag_t = typename name_tag_traits<T>::tag_type;

    // same as above but returns a list of value types
    template <class T>
    using name_tag_value_t = typename name_tag_traits<T>::value_type;

    template <class T> struct Base {};
    template <class... Ts>
    struct TypeSet : Base<Ts>... {
        template <class T>
        constexpr auto operator + (Base<T>) {
            if constexpr (std::is_base_of_v<Base<T>, TypeSet>) {
                return TypeSet{};
            }
            else {
                return TypeSet<Ts..., T>{};
            }
        }
        constexpr auto size() const -> std::size_t { return sizeof...(Ts); }
    };

    // checks if tags are unique
    template <class... Types>
    constexpr auto are_tags_unique() -> bool {
        constexpr auto typeset = (TypeSet<>{} + ... + Base<name_tag_t<Types>>{});
        return typeset.size() == sizeof...(Types);
    }

    template <class Needle>
    constexpr auto index_of_impl(size_t index, size_t end) -> std::size_t {
        return end;
    };

    template <class Needle, class T, class... Haystack>
    constexpr auto index_of_impl(size_t index, size_t end) -> std::size_t {
        return std::is_same<Needle, T>::value
            ? index
            : index_of_impl<Needle, Haystack...>(index + 1, end);
    };

    // find the index of T in a type list, returns sizeof...(Haystack) + 1 on failure (think std::end())
    template <class Needle, class... Haystack>
    static constexpr auto index_of() -> std::size_t {
        return index_of_impl<Needle, Haystack...>(0, sizeof...(Haystack) + 1);
    };

}; // namespace detail

// and here's our little wrapper class that enables tagged tuples
template <class... TypePairs>
class tagged_tuple : public std::tuple<detail::name_tag_value_t<TypePairs>...> {
public:
    // throws an error if tags are not unique
    static_assert(detail::are_tags_unique<TypePairs...>(), "Duplicated tags!");
    // not really needed for now but if we switch to private inheritance it'll come in handy
    using tag_type = std::tuple<detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>;
    using value_type = std::tuple<detail::name_tag_value_t<TypePairs>...>;
    using value_type::value_type;
    using value_type::swap;
    using value_type::operator =;
};

// our special get functions
template <class Name, class... TypePairs>
auto get(tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>& tuple) -> typename std::tuple_element<
    detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>(),
    typename tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>::value_type>::type& {
    return std::get<detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>()>(
        tuple);
};

template <class Name, class... TypePairs>
auto get(const tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>& tuple) -> const typename std::tuple_element<
    detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>(),
    typename tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>::value_type>::type& {
    return std::get<detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>()>(
        tuple);
};

template <class Name, class... TypePairs>
auto get(tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>&& tuple) -> typename std::tuple_element<
    detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>(),
    typename tagged_tuple<TypePairs...>::value_type>::type&& {
    return std::get<detail::index_of<Name, detail::name_tag_t<TypePairs>...>()>(
        std::move(tuple));
};
```

And the syntax would be:

```
// main.cpp
using foo = tagged_tuple<type_pair<class bar, int>, type_pair<class baz, std::string>>;
foo a{ 1, "foo" };
std::cout << get<bar>(a) << " " << get<baz>(a);
```

Output:

```
1 foo
```

Everything went fine until I tested this piece of code:

```
std::tuple<int, std::string> a{ 1, "foo" };
foo b{ a };
```

which in my theory should work since tagged_tuple is derived from std::tuple and it has a constructor for that case. I then tested in Visual Studio 2019 and it totally worked. But when I try with gcc/clang, I got this error:

```
 error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'foo' (aka 'tagged_tuple<type_pair<class bar, int>, type_pair<class baz, std::string>>')
    foo b{ a };
```

Which is weird since I already included all the base class' constructors with `using value_type::value_type` (to my knowledge). Then I added the following constructor:

```
template <class... Types>
constexpr tagged_tuple(std::tuple<Types...> &tuple) : value_type(tuple) {}
```

And this time it worked. I can't understand why it wouldn't work without this piece of code.

Is there a bug in gcc/clang or I am missing something?

Comment: It compiles if I change that to `using typename value_type::tuple;`, but I didn't think you needed `typename` there. Maybe you do with the alias.

Comment: Update: It seems like Visual Studio 2022 also doesn't work. Maybe it's just a VS 2019 thing?

Comment: @chris I changed to that and this time clang worked but gcc didn't. What the hell is happening here

Comment: I'm willing to bet you've discovered at least one compiler bug as can happen with heavy templates, but it could also be something like IFNDR where all compilers would be correct.

Comment: You can’t inherit copy constructors, so it may depend on the details of one of the constructors for converting from another `tuple` type.

Comment: @DavisHerring Ah I got it.  Now I know that using base_class::base_class won't inherit copy and move constructors. Thanks!